# Find the probability $P(A^c \cap B^c)$ when only given $P(A), P(B)$.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given the following question:

> Given 2 events $A$, $B$ where:
>
> $P(A) = 0.4$, $P(B^c) = 0.7$, $P((A \cup B)^c) = 0.3$
>
> Does $A$ and $B$ dependent each other?

I infered that $P(B) =1 - P(B^c) = 1 - 0.7 = 0.3$.

According to `DeMorgan laws` I know that $P((A \cup B) ^c) = P(A^c \cap B^c)  = 0.3$.

All I have to know is whether $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = 0.3^2 = 0.09$.

Using all I have, how can I infer $P(A \cap B)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the first line, doesn't it state that $P(B^c)=0.7$ and then $P(B)$ should be equal to $0.3$?

Comment: Draw a venn diagram and proceed from there for sets A and B.

Comment: The title of the question is wrong, you want to find $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @Eoin My bad, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)
$$
$$=P(A)+(1-P(B^c))-(1-P((A\cup B)^c))$$
$$=P(A)-P(B^c)+P((A\cup B)^c)$$
This final thing is equal to zero, so they are not independent.

Comment: I got:

$(P(A \cap B) = 0) \ne (P(A)P(B) = 0.4 \cdot 0.3)$

Same as yours?

Comment: @Billie Yes $P(A\cap B)=0$. I didn't calculate P(A)P(B) in my answer, but it clearly isn't zero, so they can't be independent.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A^c \cap  B^c) = P(A^c) + P(B^c) - P(A^c \cup B^c) = 1 - P(A) + 1 - P(B) - P(A^c \cup B^c)$.